# Error Order By clause - difference between SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-order-by

I'm having a problem understanding what it's happening. I'm using a SQL Server 2008 R2 for a database and I'm starting to migrate to SQL Server 2012.

In the process, I come across this error in SQL Server 2012:

> Column XXXX is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

The problem is I'm making the exact same query in the exact same database. In SQL Server 2008 R2, it returns the data with no syntax error at all, but SQL Server 2012 throws the error.

I understand that it's correct to have the syntax error. The order by clause should be:

```
order by cupo_fvence
```

But if this is correct, why is it working in SQL Server 2008 R2?

The query is:

```
select 
    cupo_fvence = MAX(cupo_fvence), ec.espe_codigo
from 
    espe_cupones ec, especies e
where 
    e.espe_codigo = ec.espe_codigo
    and e.espe_activa = 1 -- activas
    and e.tesp_codigo in ('T','E','O','N','W','P','Y') 
group by 
    ec.espe_codigo
order by 
    ec.cupo_fvence
```

Thanks in advance

In SQL Server 2008 R2:

[image: SQL Server 2008 R2]

In SQL Server 2012:

[image: SQL Server 2012]

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Did you try to change `MAX(cupo_fvence)` to `MAX(ec.cupo_fvence)`?

Comment: Must be ORDER BY 1 or ORDER BY MAX(cupo_fvence) or ORDER BY cupo_fvence. By the way, SQL Server 2008 R2  gives the same error

Comment: Actually that was a behavior change for 2005 - which indicates that your "2008" database is using an **ancient** compatibility level. See: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143359(v=sql.90).aspx
And thanks for posting the same question independently to both so and msdn.